# Text Based game JTextArea does not displaying JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

Ok, so I am making a text-based java game like Zork.  I am doing with a simple GUI, that has a JTextField
JTextArea ETC.  I am having extreme difficulty having the user type in the textField for instance, "North" and have the JTextArea even say north let alone do a command.  Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop.Action;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class gameFrame {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create variables for graphics
        String a = ("Adventure");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(a);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField input = new JTextField(25);
        JTextArea output = new JTextArea("Hello", 65, 30);
        JMenu exit = new JMenu("Exit");

        //add main parts together
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(input);
        panel.add(output);


        //frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(900, 600);

        //panel
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //input
        input.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
        String inputBox = input.getText();



        //output
        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);


        }


    }
```

Comment: I have set the code to if then instead of do while and it works now but how do i mkae the jtextfield trigger to say you went north?  Just typing on north doesnt do anyting, it needs to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you compare strings in java with a `do .... while ....` loop. Have you tried something like this?

```
String inputBox = input.getText();
do {
  // Code to do whatever when inputBox equals "north"
  output.append("You went: North");
}
while(inputBox.equals/*IgnoreCase*/("north");
```

What you can also do is add an `ActionListener` to the JTextField. When clicked enter, display the contents of the JTextField on the JTextArea.

```
input.addActionListener(
  new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      output.append(inputBox.getText());
    }
  }
);
```

This is uncompiled, and unchecked.

Comment: When I run my input block all I get is "You went North" without actually typing anything it just happened?

Comment: The ActionListener will occur as soon as you click enter, no matter what you type in.

Comment: When I opened the program it just said "You Went North", before I did anything.

Comment: Oh. Well, sorry about that. As I said, I didn't check it.